# Why cannot use 'map or filter' in testing library with typescipt?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing

I cannot use to array method for testing library.

My test code is like below.

```
const ListTitle = fakeData.forEach((el) => {
      el.filter((element: string | object) => (typeof element === "string" ? element : element?.props?.children));   **** filter method has a error ts.2339
    });
```

Attached, I want to exclude only text in fakeData array.

fakeData is like below the code.

```
interface FakeDataProps {
  id:number
  titleChild:JSX.Element
}

const fakeData: FakeDataProps[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    titleChild: (
      <>
        party goes on <span style={{ fontWeight: 500 }}> The end</span>
      </>
    ),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    titleChild: (
      <>
        party goes on <span style={{ fontWeight: 500 }}>The end</span> Your time
        is ...{" "}
      </>
    ),
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    titleChild: (
      <>
        party goes on <span style={{ fontWeight: 500 }}>The end</span>
      </>
    )
  }
];
```

I expected

[
"party goes on The end",
"party goes on The end Your time is ...",
"party goes on The end",
]

But, In my test code, There are error occured that has "Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'FakeDataProps'.ts(2339)"

What shall I do?

Comment: If you do `FakeData.forEach((el) => ...` (and I assume that despite capitalization difference, `fakeData === FakeData`) then the `el` in that loop is going to refer to an **object** of shape `FakeDataProps`. Since you define it like so: `const fakeData: FakeDataProps[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typescript error is occurring because you're calling `.filter()` on an individual item. You should be calling it on the array of items like so:

```
const ListTitle = fakeData.filter((element: string | object) => (typeof element === "string" ? element : element?.props?.children));
```

There is no need for `.forEach()` in your example, just use `.filter()` as above.